# How to use. selectOption() in autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, materialize

On page load I want to initialize the autocoplete with one specific option. I am using [MaterializeCSS](https://materializecss.com/autocomplete.html) The documentation says

```
Select a specific autocomplete options.
Arguments
Element: Element of the autocomplete option.
instance.selectOption(el);
```

I tried

```
//autocomplete.selectOption("Radek")
//autocomplete.selectOption({"Radek"})
autocomplete.selectOption({"Radek":null})
```

but nothing worked. Could you suggest how to select autocomplete option programaticaly?

```
 var elemOptions = {
         data: {
            "Radek Surname ": null,
            "Radek": null,
            "Radoslav": null
        },
      minLength : 2,
    }
var elemAutomplete = document.getElementById('autocomplete-input1')
var autocomplete = M.Autocomplete.init(elemAutomplete, elemOptions);

//autocomplete.selectOption("Radek")
//autocomplete.selectOption({"Radek"})
autocomplete.selectOption({"Radek":null})
```

and working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/radek/ydar9stm/6/)

Answer (score 2):

Wow I just notice this question.
Let's just clear out something, basically Materialize Autocomplete is just a normal Materialize Input-Field but with an extra feature like dropdown options showing up when you click or type some text.

So, in order to do what you want, you must set the text value as exactly as the previously selected options text. This will make the label overlapping so you must add class `active` to the Autocomplete label (just like normally setting text value to an input field).

```js
var elemOptions = {
         data: {
            "Radek Surname ": null,
            "Radek": null,
            "Radoslav": null
        },
      minLength : 2,
    }
var elemAutomplete = document.getElementById('autocomplete-input1')
// getting the label element
var elemAutompleteLabel = document.getElementById('autocomplete-input1-label')
var autocomplete = M.Autocomplete.init(elemAutomplete, elemOptions);

// set the input element value
elemAutomplete.value = "Radek"
// then add class 'active' to the input label
elemAutompleteLabel.classList.add('active');
```

You must note that the `elemAutomplete.value` must be match with one of the `elemOptions` data.

[edited]
Only Dogfalo and God who knows what `.selectOption();` did.